# How can I remove the CSS width and height and set my own max-width from img tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I'm including my theme's css file into my application, and it contains this:

```
.status .who img {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 40px;
}
```

What I need this to look like is this:

```
.status .who img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 100%
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

but I'm not sure if I can do this from CSS alone. Do I need to use jQuery to remove the height and width from there or can I do this from CSS?

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
.status .who img {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```